# Running a scheduled task written in java on a linux server

Tags: java, linux, process

I need to run a piece of java code on a linux server everyday at a specific time.

For now I am testing it on a Ubuntu desktop by running it from the terminal and its functioning properly and as required. For scheduling, I have used the library from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule.html).

On the actual server, what would be the correct way to run this as a process ?

I mean, on my desktop, i run the code from terminal specifying a time close to current one, test it for the first time and then stop it (^Z).

On the server would it be a right way to just push it to the background ? I am sure there must be a better way of achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a shell script for executing your Java utility (you might need to add classpath and other environmental variables) and put it in your crontab.

Here is quick [crontab reference](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks for the link.. i am new to shell scripting. will try to read about it

Answer (score 5):

Run it from [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) just like you would (mostly) from the command line.  It's probably easiest to wrap it in a shell script that sets the appropriate environmental variables.

Comment: wouldn't it make platform dependent solution ?

Comment: @Jigar - yes, but he's looking for a way to run it on a Linux server.  Why worry about platform independence if it's not a requirement?  I'm reasonably certain one could write a shell script that would work across Linux variants if need be, but I suspect he only cares about the one version that he happens to be running.

Comment: I would always try to make it platform independent , even though its only linux today, we don't know what will happen tommorrow

Comment: @Jigar - why build extra complexity into it unless you know it's going to be used?  I think that's time and money wasted that could be used to do other things.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in J2EE app [Quartz Schedular](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is configured

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java SE application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system. Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually anything you may program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class features, such as JTA transactions and clustering.

- [Quick Start Guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/quick_start_guide.html)

Comment: I would use quartz too, but not should this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

i'd use crontab on a linux machine to trigger my process. Scheduling inside java works, too. but with crontab you won't have a java process running all the time, but only for your task

Answer (score 1):

There are service wrappers for linux, but its often its simplest to just

```
nohup java {etc} 2>&1 > my.log &
```

Answer (score 1):

Just can start it from cron(8). This of course assumes that your task terminates at some time. If you want to start it at system start time and having it running, then, put a start script into /etc/init.d/ with a link to the right runlevel start directory and internally use a library like Quartz to have its work scheduled.