# How can I check database field every day?Cron job?

Tags: java, oracle, sqlite, jakarta-ee, cron-task

I' m developing application in Java which is connected to database (Oracle or SQLite). In database I store contracts. The contract has field `access_date`. And i want to check this field once every day and if one day `access_date` will be equal to the current date then mark the contract as not valid. How can I implement this? In PHP as far as I know there are cron jobs for such tasks but what about java or java ee? How can I do this?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cron is not related to PHP in any way; it's just a scheduler that executes tasks periodically. You can use it to run application/script written in any language.

Comment: @a1ex07 Can you then please give me some link with information about cron.Because i don't understand the concept.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816889/running-a-scheduled-task-written-in-java-on-a-linux-server . The answer has a link to crontab manual.

Comment: Don't forget to suspend all access that depends on this attribute between midnight and when this update is committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. You can use Cron to invoke a Java program at specific time (in your
   case, one every day).
2. If your Java program is designed to run as service/daemon (staying in the background all the time), you can use a job scheduler such as [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to invoke a certain check function at specific time.
3. As an extension of 2., you can use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use either TimerTask or ScheduledTask. Here is a good tutorial for that:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving an attribute for the contract not being valid, and having to check it against sysdate every day, I would use a predicate such as "access_date < trunc(sysdate)" to find expired contracts, and an expression such as:

```
case when access_date < trunc(sysdate) then 'N' else 'Y' end
```

... to display whether a contract is active or not.

Comment: Can you please explain how to store this predicate in database and how to use this expression.I must do a query to database each time or what?

Comment: The best approach would probably be to create a view over the table that includes the expression as an additional column, and query that.